# Is the main key in package.json mandatory?

Tags: npm, package.json

I have a repo which contains a collection of a few Node.js serverless, [Function-as-a-Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_as_a_service) functions. The functions share the same `node_modules` directory, but deployed separately to our FaaS platform.

`npm init` creates a `"main": "function.js"` entry in `package.json`. Since I don't have a single (or any) entry point, I wonder if I can remove this line altogether.

Is the `main` key in [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) mandatory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it's not mandatory.

You can publish a package on npm (using the `npm publish` command) even without specifying a main entry point. So you're free to remove it from your package.json.

According to the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json#requirements), the only required fields are "name" and "version".

Comment: Thanks. For future readers, do you have an official reference from the npm documentation?

Comment: @AdamMatan - With regards to _"official reference from the npm documentation"_... According to the docs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json#requirements). it states under _"requirements"_ : A _package.json_ must have: `"name"` and `"version"` - It doesn't mention any others.

Comment: I am sorry, some questions came to my mind while reading you answer. Should the JS file specified in the `main` field of `package.json` be minified or not? Can the file specified in the `main` field be a file within a `build` or `dist` directory and thus not committed to the GitHub repo of the library? What could be the implications of such an approach and what are the best practices when developing JS libraries?

Answer (score 6):

> #### [main](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main)
>
> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your
>   program. That is, if your package is named **`foo`**, and a user installs
>   it, and then does **`require("foo")`**, then your main module's exports
>   object will be returned.
>
> This should be a module ID relative to the root of your package
>   folder.

Since you're not sharing your library with others **with require it's not mandatory**

For more info please refer to the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)